# why is my function only returning one element instead of two?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

Instructions: This function will take two arguments. The first argument should be an array. The second argument should be a number. Your function must do the following:

Begin by sorting the input array (the first argument) into alphabetical order.

Once the input array is sorted, return a new array array which is the first N elements of the input array, where N is the value of the second argument to your function:

```
function getFirstAmountSorted(inputArray, numberOfThings) {

    // Step 1 - sort inputArray alphabetically
    let bucket = input.sort();
    let citrus = bucket.slice(0, 1);
    return citrus;

    // Step 2 - create an array which contains the first items of the sorted array -
    // the number of items is provided in the second argument

    // Step 3 - return the new array you created in step 2

}
```

But when I call this function with `(['third, 'second', 'third'], 2)`, it only returns the first when it's supposed to return `'first', 'second'`. What am I doing wrong?

I haven't used the second argument in the function, because I can't figure out where to place it :')

Comment: numberOfThings isn’t being used?

Comment: yeah, I'm not sure what to do with it? I forgot to add that to my post, my bad - I need help understanding what to do with that too

Comment: Do you know how slice works?

Comment: yes, it creates a new array from another array based on the number, i.e. getFirstAmountSorted(someArray, 2);

Comment: correct the second arg of slice method -> inputArray.sort().slice(0, numberOfThings)

Comment: Referenced in Stack Overflow podcast [episode 276](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/10/09/podcast-276-ben-answers-his-first-question-on-stack-overflow/) (2020-10-09) at 02 min 48 secs.

Comment: Is it actually [TwilioQuest](https://www.twilio.com/quest#world) specific? *"TwilioQuest is an educational video game designed to teach a new generation of developers how to change the world with code. ... learning how to use your terminal, to coding in Python, JavaScript, and PHP ..."*

Comment: Mentioning TwilioQuest adds an unnecessary dimension of complexity to the post, so I've taken the liberty of editing it out of the question and answer.

Answer (score 8):

Following the [suggestion from Karan Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62500506/twilioquest-why-is-my-function-only-returning-one-element-instead-of-two/64176444#comment110531183_62500506) in the comments, I tried this code and it worked. I've made this a community wiki to reflect that.

I'll do my best to explain why I think it works.

So, in this function, numberOfitems can vary depending on what you want you want to call from your array. They want it to work for any number represented by the variable N.

The puzzle asks you to you arrange it alphabetically. When you sort inputArray, you can achieve that.

Next it asks you to return a new array array which is the first N elements of the input array, where N is the value of the second argument to your function:

When you slice that, you get a new array with a start and an end. You want it to start at 0 and end at 2. The end isn't included, so that will give you the elements 0 and 1 from your array, in other words, the first and second argument.

So when you test in const with your function:

```
getFirstAmountSorted(['cat', 'apple', 'bat'], 2);
```

you are going to get them sorted alphabetically, and then a new array with the elements at 0 and 1.

If you wrote the same function and called it like this

```
const newArray = getFirstAmountSorted(['cat', 'apple', 'bat'], 3);
```

you would get a new output with 0, 1, and 2. The goal here is to have a flexible N, not a specific [0,1], etc.

```
function getFirstAmountSorted(inputArray, numberOfItems) {
    let bucket = inputArray.sort();
    let citrus = bucket.slice(0, numberOfItems);
    return citrus;
}
```